# How to get 10 first days for each month in R

Tags: r, date, dynamic

I'm trying to generate a sequence with the first 10 days for each month from 2010 to 2016 in RStudio.

I have tried this:

```
seq(as.Date("2010/01/01"), as.Date("2016/12/11"), by = "day")
```

and this return all the days for each month, but I only need the 10 first for each month.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the generated sequence you already have, you can use function `day` of the **`lubridate`** package to filter days

```
require(lubridate)
x <- seq(as.Date("2010/01/01"), as.Date("2016/12/11"), by = "day")
x <- x[day(x) %in% 1:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base functions:

```
x = seq(as.Date("2010/01/01"), as.Date("2016/12/11"), by = "day")
x[strftime(x, '%d') %in% 1:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

The method of base function by dww has some errors, when use the strftime for getting day, that return a character, and not an integer.
So the simple way of building is that:

```
periodo <- seq(as.Date("2009-01-01"), as.Date("2022-10-12"), by = "day")
periodo <- periodo[strftime(periodo, '%d') %in% "01"]
```

That will be getting all the first day of the period. Printing "periodo", we get: (didn't place all because is too long, but I think you can understand)

```
[1] "2009-01-01" "2009-02-01" "2009-03-01" "2009-04-01" "2009-05-01" "2009-06-01" "2009-07-01"
[8] "2009-08-01" "2009-09-01" "2009-10-01" "2009-11-01" "2009-12-01" "2010-01-01" "2010-02-01"´
```

For getting all ten first days:

```
 periodo <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2022-10-12"), by = "day")
 periodo <- periodo[as.integer(strftime(periodo, '%d')) %in% 1:10]
```

I hope that I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with data frames using the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

days_df <- data.frame(ymd(seq(as.Date("2010/01/01"), as.Date("2016/12/11"), by = "day")))

days_df %>%  
  mutate(months = floor_date(days, "month")) %>% 
  filter(day(days) <= 10) %>%
  select(days) # add other columns or group as needed
```